# Inject @Value to a Path variable directly

Tags: java, spring

I want to inject Path variable directly without converting it from string like this:

```
@Value("${screenshot.path}")
private Path path;
```

property file:

```
screenshot.path=D:\Projects\myproject\screenshots
```

Error:

> Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'path'; nested
> exception is org.springframework.beans.TypeMismatchException: Failed
> to convert value of type 'java.lang.String' to required type
> 'java.nio.file.Path'; nested exception is
> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Failed to retrieve file for class
> path resource [D:/Projects/myproject/screenshots]

Is there a way to do that without injecting String and then doing Paths.get?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake, it does everything automatically, just fixed path format like this:

```
screenshot.path=D:\\Projects\\myproject\\screenshots
```